# OData REST Filter for deeply nested data

Tags: rest, filter, odata

I have a working REST request that returns a large results collection. (trimmed here)

The original URL is:

```
http://intranet.domain.com//_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\kens'&$select=AccountName,DisplayName,Email,Title,UserProfileProperties
```

The response is:

```
{
"d": {
    "__metadata": {
        "id": "stuff",
        "uri": "morestuff",
        "type": "SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties"
    },
    "AccountName": "domain\\KenS",
    "DisplayName": "Ken Sanchez",
    "Email": "KenS@domain.com",
    "Title": "Research Assistant",
    "UserProfileProperties": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "UserProfile_GUID",
                "Value": "1c419284-604e-41a8-906f-ac34fd4068ab",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "SID",
                "Value": "S-1-5-21-2740942301-4273591597-3258045437-1132",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "ADGuid",
                "Value": "",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "AccountName",
                "Value": "domain\\KenS",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            }...
```

Is it possible to change the REST request with a $filter that only returns the Key Values from the results collection where Key=SID OR Key= other values?

I only need about 3 values from the results collection by name.

Comment: Can you share your original request (URI)? That would help come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In OData, you can't filter an inner feed.

Instead you could try to query the entity set that UserProfileProperties comes from and expand the associated SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties entity.

The syntax will need to be adjusted for your scenario, but I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
service.svc/UserProfileProperties?$filter=Key eq 'SID' and RelatedPersonProperties/AccountName eq 'domain\kens'&$expand=RelatedPersonProperties
```

That assumes you have a top-level entity set of UserProfileProperties and each is tied back to a single SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties entity via a navigation property called (in my example) RelatedPersonProperties.