# Filtering nested results an OData Query

Tags: rest, odata

I have a OData query returning a bunch of items. The results come back looking like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "http://dev.sp.swampland.local/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)",
            "uri": "http://dev.sp.swampland.local/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)",
            "type": "SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties"
        },
        "UserProfileProperties": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                    },
                    "Key": "UserProfile_GUID",
                    "Value": "66a0c6c2-cbec-4abb-9e25-cc9e924ad390",
                    "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "ADGuid",
                "Value": "System.Byte[]",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                },
                "Key": "SID",
                "Value": "S-1-5-21-2355771569-1952171574-2825027748-500",
                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
            }

           ]
        }
    }
}
```

In reality, there's a lot of items (100+) coming back in the **UserProfileProperties** collection however I'm only looking for a few where the KEY matches a few items but I can't figure out exactly what I need my filter to be. I've tried $filter=UserProfileProperties/Key eq 'SID' but that still gives me everything. Also trying to figure out how to pull back multiple items.

Ideas?

Comment: This looks to be an exact duplicate (with the same data) as this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920641/odata-rest-filter-for-deeply-nested-data ?

Comment: Yup, sure is. We were both working on same problem and I didn't realize he was going to post the question. My bad.

Comment: Ha, ok. Thought I was going crazy for a sec. I posted an answer to his question, so you might want to give that a try.

Comment: Appreciate it. Unfortunately the response didn't help as the service doesn't work that way. There's a different service we can use to get the properties, it just has a awkward syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you forgot about how each of the results have a key, not the UserProfileProperties so UserProfileProperties/Key doesn't actually exist. Instead because result is an array you must check either a certain position (eq. result(1)) or use the oData functions any or all.

Try **$filter=UserProfileProperties/results/any(r: r/Key eq 'SID')** if you want all the profiles where just one of the keys is SID or use

**$filter=UserProfileProperties/results/all(r: r/Key eq 'SID')** if you want the profiles where every result has a key equaling SID.